# Need to improve a query function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I built a function that takes one search term and returns results that are LIKE the term. Before the term is passed into the function, I already surround the search with single quotes and percent signs. Ex: '%search term%'

The following function works fine, parameters are not bound, but there is a prepared statement. I think it needs to be improved. Here is the one that is working (using MySQL as the db):

```
public function get_searched_ipinfo($term){
    $data = [];
    $query = "SELECT * 
    FROM ipinfo 
    WHERE office LIKE $term 
    OR vlanID LIKE $term 
    OR vlanRules LIKE $term 
    OR ipType LIKE $term
    OR ipAddress LIKE $term 
    OR ipCIDR LIKE $term 
    OR ipMask LIKE $term 
    OR hostname LIKE $term 
    OR isp LIKE $term 
    OR notes LIKE $term 
    OR url LIKE $term";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query($query);
    $ipinfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($ipinfo as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The following is what I am trying so I can improve the code. I get no results. No page crash either, so the array must be coming back empty.

```
public function get_searched_ipinfo($term){
    $data = [];
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * 
    FROM ipinfo 
    WHERE office LIKE :office 
    OR vlanID LIKE :vlanID 
    OR vlanRules LIKE :vlanRules 
    OR ipType LIKE :ipType
    OR ipAddress LIKE :ipAddress 
    OR ipCIDR LIKE :ipCIDR 
    OR ipMask LIKE :ipMask 
    OR hostname LIKE :hostname 
    OR isp LIKE :isp 
    OR notes LIKE :notes 
    OR url LIKE :url');
    $stmt->execute([
        ':office' => $term,
        ':vlanID' => $term,
        ':vlanRules' => $term,
        ':ipType' => $term,
        ':ipAddress' => $term,
        ':ipCIDR' => $term,
        ':ipMask' => $term,
        ':hostname' => $term,
        ':isp' => $term,
        ':notes' => $term,
        ':url' => $term,
    ]);
    $ipinfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($ipinfo as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I have also tried variations listed on http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/PHP.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.html

For example:

```
public function get_searched_ipinfo($term){
    $data = [];
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * 
    FROM ipinfo 
    WHERE office LIKE :office 
    OR vlanID LIKE :vlanID 
    OR vlanRules LIKE :vlanRules 
    OR ipType LIKE :ipType
    OR ipAddress LIKE :ipAddress 
    OR ipCIDR LIKE :ipCIDR 
    OR ipMask LIKE :ipMask 
    OR hostname LIKE :hostname 
    OR isp LIKE :isp 
    OR notes LIKE :notes 
    OR url LIKE :url');
    $stmt->bindParam(':office', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vlanID', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vlanRules', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipType', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipAddress', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipCIDR', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipMask', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hostname', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':isp', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notes', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':url', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $ipinfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($ipinfo as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Run an EXPALIN SELECT in phpmyadmin or workbench and see if the query uses any index or the right one.

Comment: Dont surround the parameters with the single quotes if you want a LIKE to work in a  prepared parameter. So `$term` should be `%something%` and not `'%something%'`

Comment: Cool. I removed the single quotes I was adding using the other method and it works with the 2 other methods I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you RiggsFolly. Prior to passing the search term to my function, I prepared it like this, and it worked with the initial method:

```
$term = "'" . '%' . filter_var($_POST["stringSearch"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . '%' . "'";
```

Per your advice, the change I made was:

```
$term = '%' . filter_var($_POST["stringSearch"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . '%';
```

It works fine now with this iteration of the function:

```
public function get_searched_ipinfo($term){
    $data = [];
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * 
    FROM ipinfo 
    WHERE office LIKE :office 
    OR vlanID LIKE :vlanID 
    OR vlanRules LIKE :vlanRules 
    OR ipType LIKE :ipType
    OR ipAddress LIKE :ipAddress 
    OR ipCIDR LIKE :ipCIDR 
    OR ipMask LIKE :ipMask 
    OR hostname LIKE :hostname 
    OR isp LIKE :isp 
    OR notes LIKE :notes 
    OR url LIKE :url');
    $stmt->bindParam(':office', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vlanID', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vlanRules', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipType', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipAddress', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipCIDR', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ipMask', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hostname', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':isp', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notes', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':url', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $ipinfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($ipinfo as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you could do various improvements from making an array that holds the office, vlanRules and others and implode it for columns and array fill or a loop to set $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, '%'.$value.'%'), then the foreach for looping over fetchAll is superfluous, as fetchAll already returns an array

Comment: Lawrence, you are right. This part is redundant:

```
$ipinfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($ipinfo as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
```

I changed it to:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $results;
```